# Arabic words doesn't appear in select list

Tags: html, arabic

I would like to select data from table in DB to a dropdown list (select list)
But these date are in Arabic Language so I found all the Arabic words appears "?????"

I did this tags in my select list and also doesn't work!

```
<select name="x" dir="rtl" lang="AR">
```

Also in the header I added this tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

My DB encoding is: utf8_general_ci

This is a screen shot from the problem

[image: Look, no Arabic in the dropdown here]

Note: I showed data in Arabic from DB to the normal page in table td and it worked fine, so the problem is in the select statement/list (dropdown list)

Comment: Sounds like the author of the database did not specify what charset encoding was used.  What database management system are you using?

Comment: If the problem is with text that comes from a DB, you should really show us your code that reads the DB.

Comment: My DB encoding is: utf8_general_ci

Comment: It looks like an encoding problem, where your Arabic characters are replaced with a generic '?'. +1 for showing that it *does* work with hardcoded text. Can you verify that you get a useful string back from your database? ~x~Try writing it out using an alert, or injecting it into HTML or such.~x~ I now see you tried that. Can you check if it's UTF8?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the column type as nVarchar instead of varchar in the Database table. 
Also, you need to declare the SQL parameters as nVarchar in your ADO.NET.